# How to compare each words of string with another - uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to take each word from a string and need to check if it is same as another string. Order of words may not same for two strings. But it should return true results.

For example :

```
          StringtoCompareWith="hi you should do this";
          InputString1="you hi should this do";
          InputString2="you hi ";
```

when compare "InputString1" with "StringtoCompareWith" it should return a true result. And if it is with "InputString2" it will return false. How can I achieve this in a fastest way ?

Comment: So you want to tokenize your compare string, and your input string, and ensure that each has all the words that the other does?

Comment: Split both the sentences into an array of words and then iterate through each word from smallest array. Time complexity O(n). Do you want less than this?

Comment: @john yes with least time of running

Answer (score 3):

Split both strings and use `Except`, but also check that both contains the same number of words.

```
var StringtoCompareWith = "hi you should do this";
var InputString1 = "you hi should this do";

var first = StringtoCompareWith.Split();
var second = InputString1.Split();

bool isEqual = first.Length == second.Length && !first.Except(second).Any();
```

Comment: You have no split delimiter.

Comment: It is not needed here: check the docs: If the separator argument is null or contains no characters, the method treats white-space characters as the delimiters.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Same answer, but using foreach loop. Here you can split sentence into words and check if one of the two array contains each word.

Here is the code:

```
 using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string StringtoCompareWith="hi you should do this";
        string InputString1="you hi should this do";
        string InputString2="you hi ";

        bool isEqual = CheckString(StringtoCompareWith, InputString1);
        //bool isEqual = CheckString(StringtoCompareWith, InputString2);

        Console.WriteLine(isEqual ? "Both are equals" : "Not equal");

    }
    public static bool CheckString(string inp1, string inp2){
        string[] split1 = inp1.Split(' ');
        string[] split2 = inp2.Split(' ');

        //Worst case: when lenght are not same
        if(split1.Length != split2.Length)
            return false;
        else{
            //Time complexity: O(n) 
            foreach(string s1 in split1){
                if(!inp1.Contains(s1))
                    return false;
            }
        }
    return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the link: [dotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lvQ4gN)

Answer (score 0):

Split your string on Space, keep only the not null value then check if all of them are in the reference array with [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx). You can also clear duplicate from the list if you need to.

```
string StringtoCompareWith = "hi you should do this";
string InputString1 = "you hi should this do";
string InputString2 = "you hi ";

var result = StringtoCompareWith.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).OrderBy(x => x)
                        .SequenceEqual(InputString1.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).OrderBy(x => x));
```

Comment: What if `StringtoCompareWith ` contains all the words from `InputString1` plus some more ... ?  it won't work.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten, You are right.. But op is unclear on this point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this-

```
string StringtoCompareWith = "hi you should do this";
string InputString1 = "you hi should this do";
string InputString2 = "you hi";

var arr1 = StringtoCompareWith.Split(' ');
var arr2 = InputString1.Split(' ');

bool check = arr1.Count() == arr2.Count() ? ((arr1.Intersect(arr2).Count() == arr1.Count()) ? true : false) : false;
```

So I am comparing `StringtoCompareWith` to `InputString1` which you can change as per your needs.